# How to fetch phone numbers from string?

Tags: php

I have string whom fetch from database but all having different format so how can i fetch phone numbers from that strings

String Examples

```
user name;foo@foo.com;0373XXXXXX;fooo;ccc    
user name;foo@foo.com;fooo;0373XXXXXX;ccc    
user name;0373XXXXXX;foo@foo.com;fooo;ccc
```

and here 0373XXXXXX is 10 digit phone number of user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code :

```
<?php

$string = "user name;foo@foo.com;0373123456;fooo;ccc";

preg_match_all('!\d+!', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);

?>
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks Milan It works